# Current thread count while using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute

Tags: multithreading

I am using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute to execute my method, inside my method I copy files to a drive, after copying, i will rename my file.In the file name i will have to name it along with current thread count i.e if the it is 1st thread my file name would be xxx_1, xxx_2 for second and so on.Is it possible to implement it?(The naming of my file will be inside my calling method)  if yes, can anyone please suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a try? and post your code.

Comment: Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();                                count++; executor.execute(new DownloadService(file, old.getTitle(), old.getid(), count)); My file will be having Title_Id_Count in its name !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static variable  and increment it in your processing method (the method which runs in separate thread)

Comment: I have did the same to implement it. Is there a way to know the count of the thread while using executors ?